# Display onedrive filelist on my website

Tags: file, onedrive

Here is the basic concept of what I am trying to do.  My web app allows my clients to log in to a dashboard.

One of the things I want to show on their dashboard is THEIR work files.. ie: PDF files.

I store these files in OneDrive in a seperate folder for each client

Root Doc Directory
 - Client A
   - File1.pdf
   - File2.pdf
 - Client B
   - File1.pdf 
etc

so when client A logs in, I want to show all the files in the ClientA folder... 
concept sounds simple, and with storage on my own server, I can do this easy, but I cant find how to do it using OneDrive...

Does anyone out there have any ideas??  All the info I have found about OneDrive APIs requires users to actually log into onedrive which I dont want.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution for you, but on the perspective of security, should these files be public so that anyone could look at them? You said the API requires users to login. Should your application log in as yourself, read the file, and then write it to a file that a user will download and see. That way the user has no actual interaction with onedrive and you maintain its security?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about the security as well, and have decided probably the easiest way to do it is create a seperate embed link for each client folder, store the folderkey etc in the database with the rest of their details, that way they will only see their particular folder

Comment: My suggestion would be, have your application log in as you to onedrive. When a client logs in and requests his folder, the application logged in as you returns a list of files in their folder. When they select a file. Have your application read the file and store it in a temporary location in your local (server) directory with a cryptographically unique prepend/appended string so others can't guess files in the folder, and run a cleanup script to clear all 30minute+ temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're using OneDrive wrong. You should be asking each user of your service to sign in with their Microsoft Account and store the files in the user's OneDrive. Storing them all in your OneDrive means they can't access those files outside of your app (like by logging into OneDrive). Instead of using Microsoft Account as the security for those files, you're putting all of the security requirements on your own ability to protect access to your OneDrive account. Basically, doing it way you proposed is strongly not recommended.

You can pretty easily integrate OAuth into your website so that a user can connect your site to OneDrive and then have access to their files from OneDrive in your service.

The alternative would be to use something like [Azure Blob Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) to store/retrieve these files. Then your app would just have the set of access keys required to access storage and you wouldn't have to deal with signing into a single OneDrive account from the service and keeping the access and refresh tokens up to date.